# Extract rows in DF using condition applied on one column of DF

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that has a name in column 1, of the format :
`xxxxxxx/YYYY/MM/DD/xxxxxxxx` where the date appears in the name.

I want to extract only those row of the DF which have a date in their name within a specified date range.

```
date_df=tmp_DF['UId'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

gives another data frame with yyyy, mm and dd as columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with values between `//`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].str.extract(r'/(.*)/', expand=False))
```

Or with specify `YYYY/MM/DD` digits:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})', expand=False))
```

Last for filter by range of datetimes use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['date'].between('2023-03-21', '2023-05-01')]
```

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})', expand=False)) This adds a column to the DF. But I want to extract out only those rows that contain the date within a particular range

so my resulting DF should have only those filtered rows